# Product of non commutative periodic elements which is NOT periodic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof, monoid

There is a proposition which says:

> If $a$ and $b$ are two periodic elements of a monoid $(G,\cdot\,,1)$ such that $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$, then $a \cdot b$ is a periodic element of the monoid $(G,\cdot\,,1)$.

I tried to find a counterexample. I thought of matrices. I didn't find two $2 \times 2$ matrices so I tried with $3 \times 3$ but no result. I thought also to try with functions. I am searching two elements $a$ and $b$ of finite order such that $a \cdot b \neq b \cdot a$ and $a \cdot b$ is not of finite order. Since I didn't find a counterexample, I thought it may be true also the converse.

Any help to find two non commutative periodic elements such that their product is non-periodic? Is the converse true: $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$ and $a \cdot b$ periodic implies $a$ and $b$ are periodic?

Comment: The question was badly formated (please take care of this next time) and is not complete as it is written now. What is a periodic element of an algebraic structure? And what does $a * b$ mean when you talk about arbitrary algebraic structures? Are you maybe only interested in groups?

Comment: Anyway, the answer to the last question is of course No (in the case of groups). Please think about the simplest element $a * b$ can be.

Comment: And you are looking for a counterexample to *what*? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Yes, the result was for groups, i wanted to be more general, at least it as to be a monoid to have the identity element

Comment: I think that by "periodic" you mean "of finite order". If you [edit] the question to clarify we may be able to help. One does not have noncommutative elements of a group, you have pairs of elements that do not commute.

Comment: I am searching two elements a and b of a monoid such that they do not commute ab !=ba, i want a and b periodic so it must exist a non zero integer n such that a^n=1 and a non zero integer k such that b^k=1 , this two elements must be such that a*b is a periodic element

Comment: When i say a periodic element i mean an element of finite order

Comment: @John: every element of a finite group has finite order, so you can take $a, b$ to be any two noncommuting elements in a nonabelian finite group, e.g. a transposition and a $3$-cycle in $S_3$.

Comment: I have a proposition that says that : a,b  \in(G,•,1), a ,b periodic elements and ab=ba than ab is periodic. I wanted to know if commutative property was necwssary or it was only to make the proof more easy. Than i wanted to know if the proposition could be inverted

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: have you an example in an infinite monoid?

Comment: @JohnPi take a direct product of Qiaochu's example with an infinite monoid

Comment: @Lukas Heger: Maybe i am wrong...i counterexample must be two periodic elements that not commute each other but the product is non periodic

Comment: That is the opposite of what you just said. Anyway, you can find a counterexample in $2 \times 2$ matrices; take two reflections through axes at an irrational angle from each other (I mean an irrational multiple of $\pi$). Their product is an irrational rotation.

Comment: @Quiaochu: how this matrices are made?

Comment: @John: I wrote an answer with details.

Answer (score 3):

You have phrased your question confusingly multiple times (I think there were multiple accidental word substitutions) but I think you are asking the following two questions:

1. Is it true that if $a, b \in G$ are two elements of a group which don't necessarily commute, and $a, b$ have finite order, then $ab$ must have finite order?
2. Is it true that if two elements $a, b \in G$ of a group commute and $ab$ has finite order then $a, b$ have finite order?

The answer to both questions is no. For the first question you *can*, in fact, find a counterexample in $2 \times 2$ matrices: take two reflections across two axes at an irrational angle apart (I mean an irrational multiple of $\pi$). These have order $2$ but their product is an irrational rotation which has infinite order. Explicitly you can take

$$a = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right], b = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & - \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$$

where $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$, e.g. $\theta = 1$. We have $a^2 = b^2 = 1$ but their product

$$ab = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$$

is a clockwise rotation by $\theta$. By using other values of $\theta$ we can arrange for the product $ab$ to have any finite order. $a$ and $b$ generate, depending on the angle $\theta$, either a [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) or an [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group).

For the second question you can take $a$ to be any element of infinite order in any group, e.g. $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $b = a^{-1}$, so that $ab = ba = e$.

Comment: Good examples! Thanks